# Formik COnditional Validation based on Form Values

Tags: reactjs, forms, typescript, formik, yup

I have a somewhat complex form. It has 3 Basic Types based on the type of the HTTP Request I am making **(POST_USER, PUT_USER, PUT_PASSWORD)**. On top of that, in the case of **(POST_USER)**, I need to select the Type of User I want to create. Between **(BASIC & NON_BASIC)**.

I am using `React`, `Formik` and `Yup` for the Validation. The validation based on the **HTTP_REQUEST** is working perfectly.

The problem is that I want to check based on the form Values, and the `ValidationSchema` from `Formik`, that I am using is not passing them as props. So, I cannot pass an argument to the Validation Function I am passing through to `ValidationSchema`. Here is the Function that I am using, for the validationSchema.

```
export const VALIDATION_RULES = (execMode: executionMode): any => {
  switch (execMode) {
    case executionMode.PUT_USER:
      return Yup.object().shape({
        username: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Name is required'),
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .nullable(),
        groups: Yup.array().required('Group is required')
      });
    case executionMode.PUT_PASSWORD:
      return Yup.object().shape({
        password: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Password is required'),
        confirmPassword: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Password confirmation is required')
          .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match')
      });
    default:
      return Yup.object().shape({
        type: Yup.mixed()
          .oneOf([AuthenticationType.BASIC, AuthenticationType.NON_BASIC])
          .required('Authentication Type is required'),
        username: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Name is required'),
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .nullable(),
        password: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Password is required'),
        confirmPassword: Yup.string()
          .trim()
          .required('Password confirmation is required')
          .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match'),
        groups: Yup.array().required('Group is required')
      });
  }
};
```

The executionMode, is a simple Enum. I am using it in both the above function as well as the component itslef:

```
enum executionMode {
  POST_USER = 'POST_USER',
  PUT_USER = 'PUT_USER',
  PUT_PASSWORD = 'PUT_PASSWORD'
}

export default executionMode;
```

Here is my Component where I call `Formik` itself:

```
      <Formik
        initialValues={this.getDefaultValues(Mode)}
        validationSchema={VALIDATION_RULES(Mode)}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        render={({ isSubmitting, values, status }) => (
          <Form>
            ..Form Related Code. Doesn't have anything to do with validation
          </Form>
        )}
      />
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
The validation as described from the code above, is working perfectly in all scenarios except the NON_BASIC POST_USER Form. The problem there, is that it doesn't allow me to create the User, since the validation for Password and ConfirmPassword still exists, in the validationSchema itself.

POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:
1. I tried using `validate` from Formik, which passes the values as props, but the logic for mapping the errors to the values needs to be re-written which is quite a letdown. On top of that, there is some more custom code, that I need to create, like handling errors onChange and onBlur which validateSchema, is handling perfectly on its own.
2. I also tried using `when` from yup. It doesn't work. It passes the validation, submit the form, and return the server errors.

**If you can help I would really appreciate it. Please do not mark this as duplicate. It is not as simple as using `when`, and there is very limited documentation online on how to use `validate` and what I need to do with the error mapping and handling change on events. Thank you for your time..**

Comment: Just a thought... You have 3 different modes with 3(?) different sets of fields. Would it be better in your case to write 3 different forms, one for each mode? In this case you will have separate validation schemas per use-case.

Comment: Even if I do that, the case of the `when`, for the Create From Remains. Also, I would need to test 2 different Components. right the same code for making 3 calls. Wire up Redux for each different form. I understand what you are saying, and I struggled with that decision, but I believe, that is a better solution for my setup. Thank you!!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the `when` case is what giving you problems. What if you "eliminate" it by having 4 modes. Split your `POST_USER` mode into `POST_USER_BASIC` and `POST_USER_NON_BASIC`, and have 4 validation schemas. Would it work for you?